# ASP.NET Core MVC web app - reusable code and reusable multi-select combo box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

A while back there was a functional multi-select dropdown javascript library that allowed users to search though items available in the drop down. That unfortunately hasn't been working with Bootstrap 5 and I built my own html/css to manage that in conjunction with some of Bootstrap 5's capabilities.

What I'm struggling with is how to make the html and associated models reusable within ASP.NET Core 7 MVC.

What I did was create a DropDownOptions Model Class, containing the drop down title and it's items. Then I have the primary models for pages using multiples of that DropDownOptions class model. One DropDownOptions property for each drop down on the page. It's working great! With the exception that I have to duplicate the HTML for each DropDownOption on the view page.

I need:

- Drop downs to update the @model of the ExportView page.
- Reusable html/code that reduces maintenance of simple common things for the site like a Drop Down/Combo Box.
- At some point, have Ajax like functionality that updates/filters Property2 based on what was selected in Property1.

I've tried view components and that doesn't work the model on the main view page never is updated from the view component.

I'm not sure if an editor template will work here to encapsulate the dropdown HTML as from most of what I've read, the editor template code that can be used is a fairly hacky bit of code. See [GSerg's Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333332/correct-idiomatic-way-to-use-custom-editor-templates-with-ienumerable-models-in) and the response by GSerg again directly below the OP.

Reusable code seems to be messy at best with ASP.NET Core MVC generally speaking. Having a hard time sifting through Google to find a good answer.

The view page looks like this:

```
@model MyApp.Web.Models.ExportViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Export";
}

@*Below is an example of side by side divs and then stacked side by side divs*@
<div style="max-width: 1200px;">
    <form asp-controller="Export" asp-action="SubmitForm" method="post">

        <div class="grid-container">

            <div id="property1-dropdown-box" class="custdropdownpicker">
                <div class="custdropdownpicker-selection-container">
                    <label id="property1-label" class="custdropdownpicker-selection-label">@Model.Property1.DropDownTitle</label> Select... <img id="thisismyid" class="custdropdownpicker-icon" src="~/images/chevronsBlueDown.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="property1-items" class="custdropdownpicker-items custdropdownpicker-items-hidden">
                    <label id="property1-searchlabel" class="custdropdownpicker-searchlabel">Search: </label> <input id="property1-searchbox" class="custdropdownpicker-searchbox" type="text" />
                    <br />
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Property1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="custdropdownpicker-itemcontainer custdropdownpicker-itemcontainer-visible">
                            <input class="custdropdownpicker-checkbox" type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Property1.Items[i].IsChecked" value="true" />

                            <label class="custdropdownpicker-item-label" asp-for="@Model.Property1.Items[i].IsChecked">
                                @Model.Property1.Items[i].ItemName
                            </label>

                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Property1.Items[i].ItemName" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Property1.Items[i].Id" />

                            <br />
                        </div>
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="custdropdownpickercolumnseparator">&nbsp;</div>

            <div id="property2-dropdown-box" class="custdropdownpicker">
                <div class="custdropdownpicker-selection-container">
                    <label id="property2-label" class="custdropdownpicker-selection-label">@Model.Property2.DropDownTitle</label><img id="thisismyid2" class="custdropdownpicker-icon" src="~/images/chevronsBlueDown.png" />
                    <label id="property2-selected-items">Selected Items Values</label>
                </div>
                <div id="property2-items" class="custdropdownpicker-items custdropdownpicker-items-hidden">
                    <label id="property2-searchlabel" class="custdropdownpicker-searchlabel">Search: </label> <input id="property2-searchbox" class="custdropdownpicker-searchbox" type="text" />
                    <br />
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Property2.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="custdropdownpicker-itemcontainer custdropdownpicker-itemcontainer-visible">
                            <input class="custdropdownpicker-checkbox" type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Property2.Items[i].IsChecked" value="true" />

                            <label class="custdropdownpicker-item-label" asp-for="@Model.Property2.Items[i].IsChecked">
                                @Model.Property2.Items[i].ItemName
                            </label>

                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Property2.Items[i].ItemName" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Property2.Items[i].Id" />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    }
                    <br /><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="SubmitForm">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The `DropDownOptions` class looks like this:

```
public class DropDownOption
{
    public string DropDownTitle { get; set; } = "";

    public List<DropDownOptionItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<DropDownOptionItem>();

    public int PageDisplayOrder = 0;

    public DropDownOption() { }

    public DropDownOption(string dropDownTitle, int pageDisplayOrder)
    { 
        DropDownTitle = dropDownTitle; 
        this.PageDisplayOrder = pageDisplayOrder; 
    }

    public DropDownOption(string dropDownTitle, int pageDisplayOrder, List<DropDownOptionItem> items) : this(dropDownTitle, pageDisplayOrder)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public class DropDownOptionItem
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? ItemName { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = false;

        public DropDownOptionItem() { }

        public DropDownOptionItem(string id, string itemName, bool isChecked)
        {
            Id = id;
            ItemName = itemName;
            IsChecked = isChecked;
        }
    }
}
```

The Page model looks like this:

```
public class ExportViewModel
{
    public DropDownOption Property1 { get; set; } = new DropDownOption("Property1", 1);

    public DropDownOption Property2 { get; set; } = new DropDownOption("Property2", 2);

    public ExportViewModel() { }

    public ExportViewModel(string environmentRootPath, HttpContext _contex)
    {
        // ... some logging code

        // ... code to load Property1.Items and Property2.Items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else struggling with this... This was how I ended up getting a partial view to reference the parent view's model.  It all boils down to creating your partial view and parent view in a way that the partial view "asp-for" attributes end up taking on a naming convention that will ultimately pair the partial view up with the parent view's pathing to objects by name space and property name.

The Parent page was changed to the following.  Note the "new ViewDataDictionary" which per Microsoft, is a copy of the ViewData/ViewBag sent to the Partial View.  In my situation, I want to tie this Partial View back to a specific property, so I'm passing the property name into the Partial View's ViewData.

In the PartialView definition, the important aspects are the "asp-for" attributes, where specifying the path to the property of the parent model is the main point.  While I do have ID's being set with naming to match the property, I don't believe that code is crucial.  That's more for better identifying and where it's coming from once generated.

Key changes:

- Property1 and Property2 were moved into a Dictionary.  I probably could have left them as properties, but I ended up simply liking how this all played out.
- PropertyName was added to the DropDownOption class.  Also could have probably done without this but it did make it fairly simple to use the PropertyName value to create id's throughout the partial view.

See below.  Fyi, there is some JavaScript in the backend of this to make this all work from a dropdown perspective, but the code points below answered how I get a PartialView to reference a ParentView's model.

```
@model MyApp.Web.Models.ExportViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Export";
}

@*Below is an example of side by side divs and then stacked side by side divs*@
<div style="max-width: 1200px;">
    <form asp-controller="Export" asp-action="SubmitForm" method="post">

        <div class="grid-container">

        @await Html.PartialAsync("_DropDownOptionPartialView", Model, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { {"PropertyName", "Property1"}})
        
        <div class="custdropdownpickercolumnseparator">&nbsp;</div>

        @await Html.PartialAsync("_DropDownOptionPartialView", Model, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { {"PropertyName", "Property2"}})
    </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="SubmitForm">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

DropDownOption Class now looks like...

```
public class DropDownOption
{

    public string PropertyName { get; set; } = "";

    public string DropDownTitle { get; set; } = "";

    public List<DropDownOptionItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<DropDownOptionItem>();

    public int PageDisplayOrder = 0;

    public DropDownOption() { }

    public DropDownOption(string dropDownTitle, string propertyName, int pageDisplayOrder) 
    { 
        this.DropDownTitle = dropDownTitle; 
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;  
        this.PageDisplayOrder = pageDisplayOrder; 

    }

    public class DropDownOptionItem
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? ItemName { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = false;

        public DropDownOptionItem() { }

        public DropDownOptionItem(string id, string itemName, bool isChecked)
        {
            Id = id;
            ItemName = itemName;
            IsChecked = isChecked;
        }
    }
}
```

Partial View definition:

```
@model PageDropDownOptions
@{
}


<div id="@(ViewData["PropertyName"])-dropdown-box" class="custdropdownpicker">
    <div class="custdropdownpicker-selection-container">
        <label id="@(ViewData["PropertyName"])-label" class="custdropdownpicker-selection-label">@Model.PageDropDownOptions[@ViewData["PropertyName"].ToString()].DropDownTitle</label> Select... <img id="thisismyid" class="custdropdownpicker-icon" src="~/images/chevronsBlueDown.png" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.PageDropDownOptions[@ViewData["PropertyName"].ToString()].DropDownTitle" />
    </div>
    <div id="@(ViewData["PropertyName"])-items" class="custdropdownpicker-items custdropdownpicker-items-hidden">
        <label id="@(ViewData["PropertyName"])-searchlabel" class="custdropdownpicker-searchlabel">Search: </label> <input id="@(ViewData["PropertyName"])-searchbox" class="custdropdownpicker-searchbox" type="text" />
        <br />
        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.PageDropDownOptions[@ViewData["PropertyName"].ToString()].Items.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="custdropdownpicker-itemcontainer custdropdownpicker-itemcontainer-visible">
                <input class="custdropdownpicker-checkbox" type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.PageDropDownOptions[@ViewData["PropertyName"].ToString()].Items[i].IsChecked" value="true" />

                <label class="custdropdownpicker-item-label" asp-for="@Model.PageDropDownOptions[@ViewData["PropertyName"].ToString()].Items[i].IsChecked">
                    @Model.PageDropDownOptions[@ViewData["PropertyName"].ToString()].Items[i].ItemName
                </label>

                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.PageDropDownOptions[@ViewData["PropertyName"].ToString()].Items[i].ItemName" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.PageDropDownOptions[@ViewData["PropertyName"].ToString()].Items[i].Id" />
                <br />
            </div>
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

View Model changed to the following:

```
public class ExportViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, DropDownOption> PageDropDownOptions { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, DropDownOption>();


    public ExportViewModel() { }

    public ExportViewModel(string environmentRootPath, HttpContext _contex)
    {
        // ... some logging code

        // ... code to load PageDropDownOptions["Property1"] and PageDropDownOptions["Property2"] classes and associated items to their instantiated classes.
    }
}
```